# How do I pass variables to shell functions in Python?

Tags: python, shell

I would like to write a Python script to automate the process of adding the dependencies of a npm package to my Open Build Service project. I have a shell function:

```
function cpobsn {
    cdobsa
    mkdir nodejs-$1
    cd nodejs-$1
    npm2PKGBUILD $1 > PKGBUILD
    cpserv
    obsa
}
```

this is the Python script I have at the moment (the `package.json` file being imported is the `package.json` of the npm package):

```
import json
import os

with open("/home/fusion809/OBS/home:fusion809:arch_extra/arch-wiki-man/package/package.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    deps = json_data["dependencies"]
    for key, value in deps.items():
        print(key)
        os.system("cpobsn")
```

I would like to pass the `key` variable to the `cpobsn` shell function (i.e., I would like this Python loop to run the shell command `cpobsn key` on every iteration). How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are good for interactive use, but this seems like a case where you want a stand-alone script instead.

If you want to have a function you can load into your `.zshrc` or similar, you could do something like the Python `__name__ == '__main__'` idiom in the script file, too.  But renaming the file to the name of the command and getting rid of the function would seem like the simplest way to achieve your end goal here.

Save this as, say, `$HOME/bin/cpobsn` and `chmod +x` it.  Make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your `PATH`, too.

```
#!/bin/sh
cdobsa
mkdir nodejs-"$1"
cd nodejs-"$1"
npm2PKGBUILD "$1" > PKGBUILD
cpserv
obsa
```

(Note the addition of proper quotes for good measure.)

Now, you can call it from Python, as with any regular external command.

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['cpobsn', key])
```

The choice between `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.check_call()` will depend on whether the script returns a useful exit code.  It doesn't at the moment, so actually `call` would be sufficient; on the other hand, you should fix that, and use `check_call` to have Python tell you when some part of the shell script failed.

Minimally, adding `set -e` to the shell script will make it check for errors, and abort if anything fails; but this often requires refactoring to avoid terminating on non-fatal errors (like `grep` not returning a result -- this is technically an error, but often an acceptable part of normal flow).

Answer (score 0):

Using Python string concatenation with `os.system` is a great security risk, a key `"foo; rm -rf /"` for example would delete all your files.

Python's `subprocess` module is much more suited for this use:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['cpobsn', key])
```

Comment: It'd be great if it weren't for the fact it returns permissions errors, namely this error: http://paste2.org/vDmHmHN4.

Comment: You need to give your script the appropriate permissions first by using `chmod`.

Comment: 'cpobsn' is a shell function, not a file. So I think this won't work.

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod +x npm2.py` before running `python npm2.py` and it returned the same error. I then tried running `sudo chmod 777 -R npm2.py` before running `python npm2.py` again and still got the same permissions error. npm2.py is the original script I gave, with your modification. So I doubt it's as simple as the file's permission.

Comment: where is your shell function defined?

Comment: In `~/Shell/obs/cp.sh` which is run by my `~/.zshrc` file (Zsh is my shell). `~/Shell/obs/cp.sh` is executable in its permissions (i.e., I ran `sudo chmod +x ~/Shell/obs/cp.sh` so I know it is executable).

Comment: I am referring to the shell script that defines cpobsn. @miracle173

Comment: @Koga: Why do you think that such a script is named 'cpobsn'? And if so, why do you thinks that such a script will execute the function? Defining a fucntion is different from executing a function.

Answer (score -1):

Just input key into `os.system` as well.

```
import json
import os

with open("/home/fusion809/OBS/home:fusion809:arch_extra/arch-wiki-man/package/package.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    deps = json_data["dependencies"]
    for key, value in deps.items():
        print(key)
        os.system("cpobsn" + " " + key)
```

Comment: Returns `os.system("cpobsn",key)` returns `TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`.

Comment: My apologies, this should have fixed it.

Comment: Is there anything else you need?

Comment: Now it's returning an error that `cpobsn` is unknown. How do I get `os.system` to run a shell script (with my `cposbn` function defined in it) before running the `cpobsn key` command?